# antlr unparsed tokens at the end does not generate error

Tags: parsing, antlr, lexer

Getting an error is usually unpleasant, but sometimes it is also unpleasant when you expect one and do not get it. My parser does not generate error for this string "2)". please suggest me a solution?

```
grammar BasicArithmetic;

options {
  language = Java;
  output   = AST;
}

expression returns [double value]: 
p1=pm{$value=$pm.value;};

// never never reference FRAGMENTS from parsers
pm returns [double value]:
p1=dm{$value = $p1.value;}
    (PLUS^p2=dm{$value += $p2.value;}|
     MINUS^p2=dm{$value -= $p2.value;}
     )*;

dm returns [double value]:
  p1=atom {$value = $p1.value;}
    ( DIV^ p2=atom {$value /= $p2.value;}|
      MUL^ p2=atom {$value *= $p2.value;}|
      POW^ p2=atom {$value = Math.pow($value, $p2.value);}
    )*;

atom returns [double value]:
  p1=Number {$value = Double.parseDouble($p1.text);}  
   | LP p2=pm RP{$value = $p2.value;};

Number: Digit+;
MUL : '*';
DIV : '/';
PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
POW : '^';
LP : '(';
RP : ')';
fragment Digit:'0'..'9';
WS :('\t'| ' '| '\r'| '\n'| '\u000C')+{$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your grammar to specify that you expect an `EOF` token after your top-level rule finishes:

```
expression returns [double value]: 
p1=pm EOF {$value=$pm.value;};
```

Comment: thank you very much. That totally makes sense. i needed a terminating rule.